# HDFS sequence file performance tuning

Tags: performance, hadoop, hdfs, sequencefile

I'm trying to use Hadoop to process a lot of small files which are stored in **sequence file**. My program is **highly IO bound** so I want to make sure that IO throughput is high enough.

I wrote a MR program that reads small sample files from sequence file and write these files to **ram disk** (/dev/shm/test/). There's another stand alone program that will delete files written to ram disk without any computation. So the test should be almost **pure IO bound**. However, the IO throughput is not as good as I expected.

I have 5 datanode and each of the datanode has 5 data disk. Each disk can provide about 100MB/s throughput. Theoretically this cluster should be able to provide 100MB/s * 5 (disks) * 5 (machines) = 2500MB/s. However, I get about 600MB/s only. I run **"iostat -d -x 1"** on the 5 machines and found that the **IO loading is not well balanced**. Usually only a few of the disk have 100% utilization, some disks have very low utilization ( 10% or less). And some machine even have no IO loading at some time. Here's the screenshot. (Of course the loading for each disk/machine varies quickly)

[image: Disk utilization]

Here's another screenshot the shows CPU usage by **"top -cd1"** command:
[image: CPU usage]

Here're some more detailed config about my case:

Hadoop cluster hardware: 5 Dell R620 machines which equipped with 128GB ram and 32 core CPU (actually 2 Xeon E5-2650). 2 HDD consist of a RAID 1 disk for CentOS and 5 data disks for HDFS. So uou can see 6 disks in the above screenshot.

Hadoop settings: block size 128MB; data node handler count is 8; 15 maps per task tracker; 2GB Map reduce child heap process.

Testing file set: about 400,000 small files, total size 320GB. Stored in 160 sequence files, each seq file has the size about 2GB. I tried to store all the files in many different size seq files(1GB, 512MB, 256MB, 128MB), but the performance didn't change much.

I won't expect the whole system can have 100% IO throughput(2500MB/s), but I think **40% (1000MB/s)** or more should be reasonable. Can anyone provide some guide for performance tuning?

Comment: I found that the attached screenshots are not clear enough after resizing so I post the screenshots on imagesHack.
Disk: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/201/diskz.jpg/

CPU: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/28/cpuzo.jpg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem myself. Hint: the high CPU usage.
It's very abnormal that the CPU usage is so high since it's an almost pure IO job.
The root cause is that each task node gets about 500 map and each map use exactly one JVM. By default, hadoop map reduce is configured to create a new JVM for a new map.

Solution: Modify the value of "mapred.job.reuse.jvm.num.tasks" from 1 to -1, which indicates that the JVM will be reused without limitation.